# I can access website even after I create firewall rule to block it’s IP address

Tags: ip, firewall, netsh

I want to block specific IP address like this:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="BlockIP" dir=out interface=any action=block remoteip=216.58.201.110
```

When I execute this command, I cant ping this IP any more.

But when I try to test it in browser, I can access it.

Can you tell me the problem? First time I block it i can’t access it, but after I undo the rule—and re-apply the same rule again—I can access specific website even when I have this rule active. This goes for every browser (Edge, Firefox, Chrome, etc…).

Is it something with web browser cache?

Comment: Are you trying to block Google.com? Because that is what I get when I go to `216.58.201.110`.

Comment: yes i was trying to block Google but it doesnt work for any other webpage

Comment: The problem is that many major websites host their sites in the cloud across different cloud servers and edge CDN servers. So the IP address will always change or at least not be consistent. So by blocking one IP address you are only blocking a moving target. If you are looking to block Google from crawling and such, look into how to block full IP ranges using their  autonomous system number (ASN) number. Depending on your skills, it can be more complicated to implement but more effective in the long run.